# Service Worker gets deleted and does not receive push event even after specifying root scope while registering

Tags: javascript, angular, push-notification, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

I am registering the service worker by using the Service-Worker-Allowed header with '/' value and specifying scope while registration.

**Registering S/W:**

> navigator.serviceWorker.register('/myapp/js/serviceWorker.js', {scope: '/'})

^ This is successful.

**Serving the S/W:**

> res.setHeader('Service-Worker-Allowed', '/');

The workflow is something like below, **myapp** is not directly called but is done behind the scenes without user seeing actual url.

User navigates to

> www.domain.com/otherapp?callmyapp=true

and behind the scenes **myapp** `www.domain.com/myapp` is initiated where I am doing above registrations with root scope.

Once user navigates to

> www.domain.com/otherapp/somethingelse&myapp=false

**myapp** is not available to the user to interact.

Earlier (while NOT using root scope) the service worker was getting redundant but now it is not. However it is marked deleted.

I don't receive any push event after this redirection.

**serviceWorker.js**

```
self.addEventListener("push", function (event) {
    console.log('sw push event');
    if (event.data) {
        const notificationData = JSON.parse(event.data.text());
        self.registration.showNotification(notificationData.title, notificationData);
    }
});
```

From what i understand with scopes is if i register the service worker with root scope it should still be available to receive push event and not get marked deleted.

I see many posts around service worker and angular, might be worth mentioning that **myapp** is old school backbone/vanilla/dust JS while **otherapp** is Angular.

**ANSWER:**

The issue was the otherApp was un-subscribing all the service workers. Only if i knew. :/ It took a while for me to debug and conclude from the logs even after explicitly caching myApp files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear what you mean by "behind the scenes" or "not available to the user to interact". The best way to get help with these kinds of issues is to create a reduced example, as in something which demonstrates the bug with all the irrelevant stuff removed.

I've tried to recreate the system you're talking about. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sw-scope-example?path=server.js:22:0.

If you visit https://sw-scope-example.glitch.me/install-service-worker/ it calls:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/deep/path/to/sw.js', { scope: '/' });
```

That service worker has a header:

```
Service-Worker-Allowed: /
```

The service worker is really basic:

```
addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(new Response('This is a response from the service worker.'));
});
```

It registers fine. Now if you visit any URL on the origin, such as https://sw-scope-example.glitch.me/other-app/whatever, you'll see the response from the service worker.

This works fine, so there's some key difference between your example & mine. Can you remix the Glitch above so it demonstrates the issue you're seeing?

Comment: Two things are happening in otherApp 1. it is deleting all the cache - so I set my own cache and still didn’t work. 2. It is unregistering all the service workers - the culprit. I was able to see some extra logs in Canary that helped me conclude this. 99% this is the reason for my s/w getting deleted. But it took a while for me to get there since I never thought that apps could be doing that too. I am extremely sorry for not digging up throughly before reaching out to you and community. Only if I knew. Is it possible to prohibit to delete s/w in a scope? I believe it is not in the root scope.

Comment: Thank you so much Jake for trying to help on this.